# rows to column conversion in excel 2003 using java code

Tags: java, mysql, excel, apache-poi

i want to convert rows to columns in excel 2003 using java on basis on certain values .

lets consider there is a value named as **doc_id** i want to convert rows of repeated doc_id in columns format. is this possible in Apache poi?
thanks in advance .

Comment: Yes, it is possible but not simple. Sounds what you really needs is a pivot table.

Comment: i tried pivoting but i couldn't make it possible